# how can we generate S3 signature from apache httpd

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an S3 private bucket where my static website hosted and I also have a proxy apache httpd.
So I want to redirect my requests from the proxy to S3.

My instance should have the access because I put in BucketPolicy the IP address of the ec2 instance :

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3_Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowWebAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.0.1/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but, when i try to serve the static website from httpd proxy, receive the error :

```
 <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>D7C96fd6A80A99E8</RequestId>
<HostId>
PmPyhF1xqK3CgG9n1tchueoLrzfakwOkB0zxbqAMJy+qhid+QTClR9kvAWD30b+VQ6UEi5YY3bc=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

My Httpd configuration :

```
ProxyPreserveHost off
<Location /static>

        ProxyPass http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket
        ProxyPass   http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket
   </Location>
```

So, I think that the problem is my httpd can't use the signature to get the authorization to access to the s3 bucket

so do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an anwser of this issue

i have to create a vpcEndoint form VPC TAB

then give the access to vpc end point in bucketpolicy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3_Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowWebAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-xxx"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyWebAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::diva-mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-xxx
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

with this configuration, we don't need to use access key and private key or signature